# Electron Dialog undefined

Tags: node.js, electron, dialog

After seen tons of stackoverflow answers about why electron Dialog and ipcMain returns undefined.
I understood that both of them must be called in the main process.

My problem is that I don't know how to declare the main process since I can't call the ipcMain. I don't know if I'm not understanding this well or I'm missing some file (I also try creating a renderer.js file to separate both processes... didn't work).

produces an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOpenDialog' of undefined
```

my **preload.js** is

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron').remote
console.log(ipcMain)
```

my **main.js** is:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

**Electron version  12.0.5**

Comment: where in main.js are you referencing dialog? That's where you'd have to do it

Comment: @pushkin I update my code to show you where I am referencing it.

Comment: Please also include your Electron version. You might have to install `remote` separately but since this info is not in your question, we can't tell if that's the case.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner 12.0.5... it's the newest version I think.

Comment: remote actually is obsolete in the newest versions. it is replaced with ipcMain and ipcRenderer, this last one is actually working for me great when I call it in preload file.

Comment: you shouldn't need to use remote here. Just refer to ipcMain directly

Comment: I do it in preload.js but: 
ipcMain is undefined @pushkin

Comment: oh, well yeah, you need to use ipcRenderer, not main to send a message. What are you trying to do with ipcMain

Comment: I'm trying to lode ipcMain and dialog because both of them don't run in the renderer process...  they run in node... to run node modules I need to do it in the main process... I create this topic since I don't know how to do it, I can't even import dialog with success neither in ipcRenderer nor in ipcMain (since this last one didn't load neither)

Comment: Finally I understood everything. In a preload file there is only exposed this modules, **electron**:
   crashReporter
   desktopCapturer
   ipcRenderer
   NativeImage
   webFrame,
So If I want to call dialog I have to call remote but Activated first since is deactivated in the newest versions

Comment: yeah. the preload script is running in the renderer, not in main, which is why you can't use ipcMain